# Is any set of disjoint touching circles(an 8 shape) on the plane countable or finite?

Tags: set-theory

So let's consider first a set of any circles which can touch each other at one point max let's denote it $C$. $C$ is countable or finite because inside(s.t. it doesn't lie on the circumference) each circle we can find a point with rational coordinates(we can project the circle to both axises and find a rational points inside these intervals) this way we show that $C$ is equinumerous to $S$, where $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ which is countable or finite.
Let's denote $E$ a set of disjoint touching circles(an 8 shape), $E$ is a set of type $C$ which is countable or finite so $E$ is countable or finite.

Is this prove correct? Please point me out if there are mistakes.

Comment: I find your question a bit hard to follow. There's an exercise I know which is "let $E$ be a set of pairwise disjoint figure-of-eight shapes in $\Bbb R^2$ (which may be scaled, translated, and rotated - *and can nest in each other*). Can $E$ be uncountable?" Is this what you're asking about? If so, I don't think your proof is correct. For example, consider the set of all circles centred at the origin - these circles are pairwise disjoint but there are uncountably many of them.

Comment: I think you're correct. Thanks for pointing it out. Then we just need to find two points with rational coordinates one inside each part of the 8 shape(we don't care if a point falls into or on the other eights). This way we will have a mapping of each 8 to a pair of points with rational coordinates(an element of a set which is obviously countable) and no two 8s can be mapped to the same pair because the set is disjoint(and if we're talking about nested 8 they can have only one point shared) so it's 1-1 mapping. Is this correct?

Comment: Indeed that's exactly the right argument for the question about figures of eight!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct if one circle cannot be inside some other circle. In that case it is correct to use $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ to prove this. In case that circles can be one inside the other, the cardinality is at most continuum. This can be easily proven by "1-1" mapping all of the circles in a plane to $\mathbb{R}^3$, by a function:
\begin{equation}
f:\{set\ of\ all\ circles\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3,\ f(C((x_0,y_0),r))=(x_0,y_0,r)
\end{equation}
Where $C((x_0,y_0),r)$ represents a circle with center $(x_0,y_0)$ and radius $r$. This mapping is "1-1" (easily proven), meaning that $Card(Your\ set)\leq Card(All\ circles\ set)=c$.